# brace-or-equal-initializer in mem-initializer

Tags: c++, syntax, initialization

The C++ standard does not allow "= *initializer-clause*" form of *brace-or-equal-initializer* (see [dcl.init]) in *mem-initializer* (see [class.base.init]). For example:

```
struct Foo {
    int x;

    Foo(int y): x = y {
    }
};
```

gives a compile-time error.

Why is that? Would there be some syntactic ambiguity if such a construct was allowed? If not, were or are there proposals to add this feature to the language?

---

Update. The semantics I would expect of such an initializer in this context is the same as of it in context of usual variable initialization. In my opinion, that would make initialization syntax of the language more consistent.

---

Update 2. As pointed out by NathanOliver, if the initialization of a member does not depend on the selected constructor and/or constructor parameters, this member can be initialized through a default member initializer (see [class.mem]). But if it does, it leaves us with using direct or list initialization.

Comment: Because it's invalid syntax, period. Finally they had to decide one.

Comment: We already have `x{...}` and `x(...)`.  Do we really need `x = ...`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But why is it invalid?

Comment: @radix I'll answer that, if you're going to offer me a real unicorn in turn.

Comment: @NathanOliver Variables can be initialized with this form of initializer, why not members?

Comment: @radix Well you can in the class body.  `class Foo { int bar = 10; };` is valid(C++11 and above).  Any constructor that does not initialize `bar` will get bar set to 10.

Comment: You're free to propose that it be allowed. However, when you do so, the default is to keep the feature out and convince people to let it in by showing that there is a worthy benefit to it being there. I do not see any such benefit.

Comment: It's a good question. There are entirely too many ways to initialize things in C++ now, and it does appear to be somewhat arbitrary what is allowed where. Moreover, despite being mostly interchangeable, in a few situations there can be a difference between forms (`vector<int> a {3, 5};` and `vector<int> a (3, 5);` are not at all the same thing). It's all a bit of a mess, and some sort of explanation might help in understanding the various forms.

Comment: @H.Guijt In my opinion, the real problem here is not the brace-initialization syntax, but the fact that `vector` has too many "utility" constructors. In pratice, it should have something like 2-3 constructors, including a generic constructor which can construct a `vector` from a range (and then the job of creating the range {5, 5, 5} could be delegated to another utility function). Anyway, always use the brace-initialization syntax, and never use the "utility" constructors of `vector`. Then you will never get a surprise

Comment: @KABoissonneault Agreed. I've been wondering whether C++ should evolve to have some sort of named parameter mechanism. It would certainly help in cleaning up this kind of mess... I.e. `vector<int> a (values={3,5});` or `vector<int> a (size=3, init=5);`

Comment: @NathanOliver But if I want the value of `bar` depend on the arguments passed to the constructor? This requires using member initializer list.

Comment: @radix, true but then you would likely use either the `()` or `{}` syntax, and not `=`. The `=` syntax, by definition, requires a single value on the right-hand-side.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz For me, the `x(y)` syntax looks like a function call and therefore indicates some non-trivial algorithm that uses its argument to construct the initial value of `x`, and the `x{y}` syntax means aggregation, i.e. the provided argument will constitute some sub-object of `x`, not `x` itself. `x = y` undoubtedly means initializing `x` itself.

Comment: @radix, `x(y)` syntax _is_ a function call (i.e. the `ctor` or `cctor` call). `x = y` could be interpreted as a constructor call, but it's not. Adding it now would just add kruft and confusion.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz I meant using such constructs as elements of a member initializer list, e.g.: `Foo { int x; Foo(int y): x(y) };`, `Foo { int x; Foo(int y): x{y} };` and `Foo { int x; Foo(int y): x = y };`, where it always is interpreted as initialization, not a function call or an assignment. I don't see why it would add confusion, as we already have initialization "by assignment" (i.e. copy initialization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, it's simple not an allowed syntax in ctor initialization.

Note that, for non-primitive classes, the `ctor() : xyz(...)` form of initialization is actually a ctor call on the type of the member `xyz`. While the `ctor(): xyz{...}` is for [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of either an array/list or for member initialization of structs/unions that have no ctors.

A `ctor() : xyz = something` would seem to have to do two things: 1) a default `ctor` call and 2) then call the `operator=` for the type of member `xyz` all of which would be **double initialization**. That is probably why it is disallowed. Of course, for non-primitive cases, I guess it could be reduced to a `copy-ctor` call to eliminate the double initialization.

Now, you could maybe convince some that allowing it for *primitive types only* would be ok, but that would likely introduce other complications into the language and compilers.

Comment: I would expect such form of initialization to use (as in all other cases) copy initialization, which involves single call to the copy constructor for non-primitive types.

Comment: @radix, as I mentioned in the answer, so agreed. However, since we have a syntax for that case already, adding `=` would just add kruft to the language. It's just the way it is.

Comment: @radix, we already have syntax for that. How would you handle the case where `x = 10` where `x` is a non-primitive type? Look for a `ctor` that takes an `int`? What if you have multiple such ctors where some of the parameters are defaulted? Why add this complication of _limited value_ when we already have syntax that covers this case and all the other cases?

Comment: It should be handled like in a variable definition `X x = 10;`.